# retrieving the subform elements in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, view, subform

How can i retrieve the elements of a subform in it's respective .phtml file?
Suppose I have 4 subforms inside main form in say w.php Then how can I display the elements of a subform in it's respective .phtml file or else all the subforms one at a time in the same main phtml file that is w.phtml?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.advanced.html shows one way.

Answer (score 0):

You might access the subforms with `$subform = $form->getSubForm($subformName);`.

Once you have the subform, you can either output it inside your view script as `<?php echo $subform; ?>`, or else you can output its elements one by one, with `<?php echo $subform->elementName; ?>`.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thank You for giving your valuable time for answering my question Dinopmi. However I tried out your solution and no form is displayed on the view page. But in the view(phtml) When I write following statement <?php $this->form->getName() ?>

Comment: Thank You for giving your valuable time for answering my question Dinopmi. However I tried out your solution and no form is displayed on the view page. But in the view(phtml) When I write following statement <?php $this->form->getName() ?> I get output in the view as 'basic_info'.

Answer (score 0):

Actually getting the subform with form->getSubform('blah')->getElement('foo')> ?>
Does not work cause it will only be rendered with as

Answer (score 0):

Get each subform in your .phtml using

```
<?php
foreach($this->element->getSubforms() as $key => $subForm){
    echo $subForm;
}
?>
```

To get the a respective element of the $subForm, just use

```
$subForm->elementName
```